# Reshaping long format dataframe to wide format according to the value of the elements in columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following pandas dataframe `X` in long format:

```
rank group ID
1    1     3
2    1     1
3    1     2
4    1     4
1    2     2
2    2     1
1    3     1
2    3     4
3    3     3
4    3     2
1    4     1
1    5     3
2    5     2
3    5     1
1    6     1
```

And I would like to reshape it to the following wide format according to the following rules:

1. split the `ID` column into 4 columns `n1,n2,n3,n4` representing the 4 elements (person) in the `ID` column.
2. for column `ni`, i=1,2,3,4, the entry in the `j`-th row is 5 minus the ranking of `i`-the person in the `j`-th group. For example, in group 3, person 4 gets rank 2, hence the 3rd row of the `n4` column is 5-2=3.
   If person `i` doesn't exist in group `j`, then the j-th entry in column `ni` is `NA`.

So basically I want to create a "score system" for person i according to the ranking: the person who is ranked 1 gets the highest score and the person who is ranked 4 gets the lowest score (or NA if that no there aren't that many people in the group).

i.e.:

```
group n1 n2 n3 n4
1     3  2  4  1 
2     3  4  NA NA
3     4  1  2  3
4     4  NA NA NA
5     2  3  4  NA
6     4  NA NA NA
```

I hope I have explained it in an understandable manner. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape the dataframe using `pivot` then subtract `5` from all the values and add prefix of `n` to column names:

```
df.pivot('group', 'ID', 'rank').rsub(5).add_prefix('n')
```

---

```
ID      n1   n2   n3   n4
group                    
1      3.0  2.0  4.0  1.0
2      3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
3      4.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
4      4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
5      2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN
6      4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```